# SDWebImage checking if image cached using Swift: Ambiguous Reference

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am trying to find out if an image has already been cached using SDWebImage but when I try to use this method I get the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'cachedIageExistsForURL".

```
let bool = SDWebImageManager.cachedImageExistsForURL(imgURL)
```

I am using Swift and I have a bridging header to use the library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`cachedImageExistsForURL`](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/b185621812f90a4eb4f7f44e0f547014da4d1958/SDWebImage/SDWebImageManager.h#L239) is not a class method on `SDWebImageManager`, it's an instance method which you need to use on the `sharedInstance`:

```
SDWebImageManager.sharedManager().cachedImageExistsForURL(imgURL)
```

Comment: As of v5.x I don't believe this will work any longer. They have shifted to these methods being asynchronous, with the result being returned in a completion block. **EDIT:** My mistake, it looks like they may have been removed even before 5.x. https://sdwebimage.github.io/sdwebimage-40-migration-guide.html

Answer (score 9):

As of `SDWebImage` 5 there is a new class, `SDImageCache`, which provides a synchronous method to use:

```
SDImageCache.shared.diskImageDataExists(withKey: urlString)
```

There is also an asynchronous method with a completion handler:

```
SDImageCache.shared.diskImageExists(withKey: urlString) { exists in
    // your code here
}
```